# Auto configuration at spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

In Spring framework, If I use Java and annotation based configuration.
Should I need to add manual configuration for spring-security or spring-Aop?

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import   
org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation
.WebMvcConfigurerAdapter;

@ComponentScan("com.ViewsController")
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
public class MvcConfig extends WebMvcConfigurerAdapter{

}
```

Answer (score 0):

No need of extra configuration to use Security and Aop in annotation based spring project, just using appropriate annotations on correct location is enough.

like use `@EnableWebSecurity` on a class which extend `WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` to enable spring security.

In order to authenticate user and role you have to override the super class method and implement your custom authentication . 
Use the following link for [spring security](https://www.baeldung.com/spring-security-login) more implementing spring security.

And for AOP use `@Aspect` and `@EnableAspectJAutoProxy` annotations on class, which contains apspectj advice's.

Answer (score 0):

In Annotation based java project, using annotation is enough, follow the tutorials on  [spring-aop](https://howtodoinjava.com/spring-aop-tutorial/), [spring-security](http://www.mkyong.com/spring-security/spring-security-hello-world-annotation-example/)